# Application Insights Wizard Failure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-application-insights

I tried to use the Visual Studio Wizard to add Application Insights to my application.  When I did it on my office computer it worked fine.  But when I tried to do it at home, it failed with the following error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not add Application Insights to project.  

Failed to install package: 
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 

with error: 
Unable to resolve dependencies.  'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.5.0' is not compatible with 

'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 2.4.1 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 2.4.0)', 
'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector 2.4.1 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 2.4.0)', 
'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 2.4.1 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 2.4.0)', 
'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer 2.4.1 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 2.4.0)', 
'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel 2.4.0 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 2.4.0)'.
```

It would seem that I have 2.5.0 installed in some parts, and 2.4 installed in other parts.  But I don't know what would cause this...  I just ran the wizard.  I had not installed anything but Visual Studio (in relation to App Insights).

I did try installing the Application Insights Status Monitor afterward, but it did not affect the error.

Any idea on how to deal with this error would be appreciated...

Details:

- I am running a Web API project
- I am running on the full .net framework (version 4.5.2)

Comment: Which framework are you targeting? And what kind of application are you developing? ASP.NET (Core), Azure Functions, UWP, ...

Comment: @rickvdbosch - ASP.NET Web API running on .NET 4.5.2

Comment: Thanks. Just tried your setup, for me this generates an ASP.NET Web API project that already has Application Insights installed. When I remove it and run the wizard, things work fine. I think you might have packages that conflict with (dependencies for) Application Insights. Could you show us your packages.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [How NuGet resolves package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution).

> Any time a package is installed or reinstalled, which includes being
>   installed as part of a restore process, NuGet also installs any
>   additional packages on which that first package depends.
>
> Those immediate dependencies might then also have dependencies on
>   their own, which can continue to an arbitrary depth. This produces
>   what's called a dependency graph that describes the relationships
>   between packages at all levels.

---

> During a package restore operation, you may see the error "One or more
>   packages are not compatible..." or that a package "is not compatible"
>   with the project's target framework.
>
> This error occurs when one or more of the packages referenced in your
>   project do not indicate that they support the project's target
>   framework; that is, the package does not contain a suitable DLL in its
>   `lib` folder for a target framework that is compatible with the project.

So, I think this is because of dependency issues of packages.

According to [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/), [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 2.4.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector/2.4.1), [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector 2.4.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector/2.4.1), [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 2.4.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web/2.4.1), [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer 2.4.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer/) and [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel 2.4.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel/2.4.0) require exactly i.e. = not >= [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.4.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.4.0) but you have [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.5.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.5.0)

So you need to downgrade the [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.5.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.5.0) to [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.4.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.4.0).

To downgrade the [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.5.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.5.0) you can uninstall the package and install the required version of the package. You can follow the following command.

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Force
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.4.0
```

Note the -**Force** parameter. Forces a package to be uninstalled, even if other packages depend on it.

Or you can try to reinstall `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` package

```
Update-Package -Reinstall Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
```

Or you can upgrade all the dependencies of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`

```
Update-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector -Version 2.5.0
Update-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector -Version 2.5.0
Update-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web -Version 2.5.0
Update-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer -Version 2.5.0
Update-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel -Version 2.5.0
```