# Could not add Application Insights to project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to configure a web app to get Live Metrics on **Application Insights**
when I try to do so I get to see this popup.

[image]

I have configured the same with a sample app it works just fine but when I try to configure with this particular app I get to see this.

Doing so also removes the **ApplicationInsights.config** file from the solution not sure why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Insights Wizard Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419324/application-insights-wizard-failure)

Comment: Could you set it in the azure portal?

Comment: hey @rickvdbosch it worked !! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install all these packages

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel -Version 2.6.4
```

it worked fine then.