# I am not able to add insigths telemetry to new Asp .NET framework project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I want to test the **Azure Insights telemetry** and for this purpose, I have created a new free Azure account and a new MVC Web App Application (Framework 4.7.2)

[image]

The App runs correctly.

After that, I tried to add the telemetry: project -> Add Application Insights telemetry

[image]

Following the wizard. I get the following error that I am not able to solve.

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not
> implemented. at EnvDTE.SourceControl.CheckOutItem(String ItemName) at
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.VisualStudio.Wrappers.VsSourceControlWrapper.d__4.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown

I tried to update the NuGet packages too. But nothing to do.

[image]

I have followed step by step the official Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net).

Some details for the installation process:

[image]

I'm having problems only with the .NET framework.

With .NET Core, anything works correctly.

Googling I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Have you installed the pre-reqs as described in the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#prerequisites

Comment: @ConnorDickson yes. Like I have followed step by step the guide.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

There are some other dependencies you need to install as well,

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer -Version 2.6.4
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel -Version 2.6.4
```

Try as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419324/application-insights-wizard-failure)

Comment: Nothing to do. The problem does not seem to be a version conflict. I receive this error anyway: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at EnvDTE.SourceControl.CheckOutItem(String ItemName) at Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.VisualStudio.Wrappers.VsSourceControlWrapper.<CheckoutFilesAsync>d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- –

Answer (score 1):

Choose the first option when adding insights, Application Insights SDK. That will install all the necessary packages.
Once that's done, you will need to add instrumentation key to the config file. Add that on top.

Your error looks more of source control rather that the project.
If you trying to work in source control and adding insights to already checked-in project, may be try creating a dummy project, and add insights to it. That will give more clarity on error, as well as help to pin-point exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with adding microsoft identity platform in VS 2022:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at EnvDTE.SourceControl.CheckOutItem(String ItemName)
```

When I changed Tools/Options/Source Control from "None" to "git" (also when I am using Git with an external tool, the error was gone.

Comment: omg, can't believe that was it. ty.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks just like one of a VS bug on a certain configuration. Try to uninstall whole VS and then install latest version again. Try another PC if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem also. The work around that eventually worked for me was to add Application Insights in Visual Studio 2017, instead of in 2019 which I normally use.

> Your error looks more of source control rather that the project. If you trying to work in source control and adding insights to already checked-in project, may be try creating a dummy project, and add insights to it. That will give more clarity on error, as well as help to pin-point exact issue.

That does not seem to be the case for me. I completely disabled source control and the problem still persisted. When I got the issue "fixed" by using VS2017 source control was running.

> To me it looks just like one of a VS bug on a certain configuration. Try to uninstall whole VS and then install latest version again. Try another PC if you can.

I tried this, did not work for me.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27044786)

Comment: hi @shinjw I'm new to posting to Stackoverflow, so maybe I'm missing something, but my response didn't actually have a new question, does it? It provides a potential solution to the original question and dismisses other potential solutions posted by anshul and Wolfrevok Cats.