# Add Application Insights Telemetry fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to add Application Insights to my WebApi app (.net 4.6.2) project. I go to the menu Project > Add Application Insights Telemetry ... > Pick my AppInsights resource in Azure then it thinks for a long time and fails.

[image]

[image]

What are the steps that are failing here and how can I get around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419324/application-insights-wizard-failure

Comment: @VovaBilyachat That's a similar but different error. That person's problem was with different versions of packages being installed. I think acceptable versions are installed here it just fails to configure itself in my project.

Comment: @Brad have you added the instrumentation key for your Application Insights (i.e..ApplicationInsights.config)?

Answer (score 2):

- While Adding Application Insights automatically we need to add instrumentation key to `ApplicationInsights.config` before closing the `</ApplicationInsights>` tag file.

  ```
  <InstrumentationKey>"your-instrumentation-key-goes-here"</InstrumentationKey>
  ```
- Then update each `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` NuGet package to the latest stable release by navigating to **Project** > **Manage NuGet Packages** > **Updates**.

If Adding Application Insights Automatically isn't working, then you can try manually from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-manually).

**REFERENCES:**
[Configure monitoring for ASP.NET with Azure Application Insights - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-automatically)

Comment: I see that after the wizard fails I am left with an ApplicationInsights.config file (created by the wizard). I can fill in the key there but the wizard has already failed and not configured the rest of the setup (not clear how much was omitted). I was hoping to avoid having to manually configure it but that appears to be the only option.